# Problems with binary generated by solc

Tags: solc

I'm compiling a contract with `solc` and I'm getting something like this (I replaced most of the hexadecimal digits with three dots to make it shorter):

```
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5060008054600...152905173__whitelist.sol:AddressSet______________91637ab6b0b491604480830192...0029
```

The thing that seems to be causing troubles is `__whitelist.sol:AddressSet______________` because when I deployed the contract in Ethereum, when I check the transaction, only the code up to that string is taken. Everything else is discarded.

When I deploy the contract using Remix, the binary looks good, without those strings in the middle.

Here is the command I'm using to compile the code:

```
solc --optimize --pretty-json --combined-json bin,abi whitelist.sol
```

Do I need to use a special flag to avoid that?

Comment: In your contract you are using a library, before you can deploy your contract you have to "link" the bytecode to the deployed address of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ismael pointed out in a comment the problem was that I was using a library and wasn't linking it. I get rid of the problem by using `--libraries` in `solc`:

```
solc --optimize --libraries "AddressSet:0x4025e920fb97ce003b361021534f0c0335254f65" --pretty-json --combined-json bin,abi whitelist.sol
```

That generated the correct binary code that can be deployed to Ethereum.